# On pseudoprimes to the base $a$ (Fermat pseudoprimes)

Tags: nt.number-theory, recurrences

In  1980, C. Pomerance, J. Selfridge, and S. S. Wagstaff defined a *pseudoprime to the base a* to be any composite odd $n$ such that $n \mid a^{n-1} - 1$.

More recently, in 2013, S. S. Wagstaff referred to such numbers as ``Fermat pseudoprimes.''

Are either of the following known to be true?---

(1) Every Lucas sequence of the form $a^{n} - 1$ contains at least one pseudoprime to the base $a$.

(2) There exists a value of $a$ for which no odd composite $n$ divides $a^{n-1} - 1$.

If neither are definitively true, could someone point me to any current research on item (2)

Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't the existence of Carmichael numbers in arithmetic progressions show that (2) can't happen?

Comment: @LSpice Please explain why.

Comment: Suppose that $a$ is a candidate for (2), and consider the arithmetic progression through $a - 1$ with spacing $a$.  Any Carmichael number $n$ in this progression is relatively prime to $a$, so is a pseudoprime to base $a$, in the sense that $n$ divides $a^{n - 1} - 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) is true.

Let $p$ be a prime such that $p\nmid (a-1)a$ and $\frac{a^p-1}{a-1}$ is composite. Then $\frac{a^p-1}{a-1}$ is a base-$a$ pseudoprime.

Also, if $q$ is a Carmichael number comprime to $(a-1)a$, then both $q$ and $\frac{a^q-1}{a-1}$ are base-$a$ pseudoprimes.